# FileMaker Pro Database Engine

Tags: database, filemaker

I have an old version of FileMaker Pro, version 7. 
Does anyone know what database engine FileMaker uses? 
I have some databases I created in FileMaker Pro that have an .fp5 extension but I can't seem to figure out what database it is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's a proprietary engine named Draco.

Comment: Thanks. That's been driving me crazy.